# How to use theme options with in_category

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I'm tring to add a theme option in wordpress to automatically assign the appropriate template to certain categories and single image templates.

I have my theme option built where a user can enter category numbers separated with a coma and I have modified the single.php template to check if the single post is in that category but the template is not being picked up.

```
<?php
$catArr = get_option('scp_gallery_cats');

if (in_category( array($catArr)))
{
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-image.php');
}
else { 
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-other.php');
}
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
global $options;
global $post;
ob_start();
$catArr = print_r(get_option('scp_gallery_cats'),false);
ob_end_clean();
if (in_category('1')) {
  include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-image.php.php');
} elseif (in_category (array(($catArr))){
  include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single_other.php.php');
} else {
  include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single_default.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a print_r($catArr); is the comma-separate list of categories one string, or is each category a separate value in the array?

If $catArr is actually a string and not an array, you'll have to do something like:

```
$catArr = explode(",", $catArr);
```

Given the below comment, I think you have to break the value into an array first; try the following code:

```
<?php
$catArr = get_option('scp_gallery_cats');
$catArr = explode(",", $catArr); //break the string into array keys!
if (in_category($catArr))
{
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-image.php');
}
else { 
    include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-other.php');
}
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Aendrew, thanks so much, print_r in the following way works 

<?php
$catArr = get_option('scp_gallery_cats');

if (in_category( array(print_r($catArr))))
{
 include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/category-4.php');
}
else { 
 include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/cats/category.php');
}
?>

The only problem is that the output of print_r is being outputted to the template also before <html>

Comment: Actually scratch that its not working its just skipping the if statement, i'll try the explore again.  The values are stored in the theme options like this "3,4,5,6,7,8" which is just entered as text